# vscode unable to authenticate extensions, github, other accounts, with OAuth web browser popup method & connection issues with WSL2, docker containers

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, oauth, network-programming, wsl-2

I've been facing this issue since I installed Bitdefender a few weeks ago.  I have their  VPN running, and docker is able to communicate docker hub with the VPN turned off or with split tunneling.  However, I am having problems with logging into GitHub and other accounts that need web logins with OAuth in the docker containers and on WSL2. Some accounts allow for device login, so I am able to use those by pasting in a code.  I was unable to make any connections from the WSL2 or containers to the internet at all until I changed the /etc/resolveh.conf to nameserver to 8.8.8.8, but that is reset every time the wsl2 or containers restart, and the problem persists even with the VPN turned off.  After trying a lot of things with the container settings keychains, etc, I able was to have it log in to GitHub with the browser window popping up, after setting up ssh and gh in the terminal, but that doesn't happen with some of the other accounts. The browser doesn't even open to authenticate, or it opens the browser and I authenticate, but vscode doesn't respond when the browser redirects after logging in.   It also displays an error "Writing login information to the keychain failed with error 'Not enough memory resources are available to process this command." I cleared out the %temp$ folder as someone suggested, but that didn't seem to help anything. Shouldn't be any problems with memory.  I'm not keen on running long strings of commands into my terminal where I don't know what they are doing.   I was also hesitant to fiddle around with registry entries as someone posted somewhere. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Do I need to open some other ports for the container?  Some of the networking stuff with Docker and WSL2 is a bit beyond me. I think Bitdefender might have changed some security policies or something.IDK.
[image]
[image]